# Clear local storage on session clear

Tags: javascript, reactjs, local-storage

I want to clear localStorage on session clear, i.e when the user exits the browser.

I am using `window.onbeforeunload` for this purpose, as shown below.

```js
window.onbeforeunload = function() {
    localStorage.removeItem('myToken');
    return '';
};
```

The problem is that this function also removes item also on browser reload.

Is there any way around this, or is it any better way on implementing this?

Edit: This is a react app, is there any hook that prevents from clearing local storage on browser reload?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `sessionStorage`. It has the same methods as `localStorage`, but it clears when the session is cleared.

Comment: I was looking for another solution, but this does the job as well.

Comment: If you wanted to delete certain keys in localStorage when a session is exited, you could delete the keys when a new session is started instead; you could set a key in sessionStorage. Then, when you would retrieve from localStorage, you could check sessionStorage first, and if sessionStorage doesn't contain the key you set before, you can safely clear the keys in localStorage because the session has changed.